# Add renderable axis object

Tags: objects

I made a nice (imho) visualization of my data that can be rendered using cycles, but is there a way to display the x,y,z axes? (what about adding text along each of them?)
I guess I could create my own solution, it just seems strange there is no way to visualize the axes.

I see in a lot of images evidence that there should be at least some way to visualize the axes.
[image: example image visualizing the axes]

Comment: There is no way, the axis are just viewport overlay. You will need to model them and render them

Answer (score 4):

I ended up creating an axis object... Here is the model [link in blend swap](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/85760).
It can create an axis and a few other interesting vectors. To create the axes,
it uses e.g. the input

```
vectors = [ 
 [(4,0,0), (0,0,0), 'red'],
 [(0,4,0), (0,0,0), 'green'], 
 [(0,0,4), (0,0,0), 'blue'], 
]
```

[image]

Comment: This saved me some time, thank you (+1)!